# Which P&S camera has a wide lens, and time-lapse shooting?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, wide-angle, timelapse, chdk

I'm looking for a camera that has:

- Wide lens (28mm or wider)
- Time-Lapse (built-it or by using CHDK)
- External power socket

and which can be found cheaply,perhaps in the second-hand market.

The camera will be used for a timelapse spanning several months.

Comment: Just a note that AFAIK no built-in time-lapse can span several months. You'll probably have to us CHDK because even with an intervalometer controller, you'll need a way to power it for  all those months.

Comment: And how would you power that camera for several months?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a timelapse with a Canon A420 and CHDK, but I just checked and that camera's only 39mm equiv at the wide end, even though it does have the other features you require.

However, I can confirm that CHDK with an intervalometer script worked very well.  Here's a timelapse movie I did with this setup: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJXGGwZ2ZCo

Looking at DPReview's camera specs, the [Canon SD800IS](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/specs/Canon/canon_sd800is.asp) for example is 28mm on the wide end, and according to the [CHDK site](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/SD800IS), will work with CHDK.

Comment: I do have a Canon SD870IS, the replacement for the SD800IS, and it is indeed wide, with a 28-105mm (equiv.) lens. I can confirm that CHDK works well with that camera. I use it to expand some of the features I need for underwater photography, but the intervalometer capability is definitely there. Power socket, no, I don't think I see one, so you will be limited to the internal battery.

Comment: @sebastien.b: If it's anything like my older Canon P&Ss, you can do something like take off the battery door and insert some sort of power adapter "brick".  I've never tried it, but that's my understanding of how you can power these cameras.  Looking at the camera specs on the Canon USA "Museum" (http://www.canon.com/camera-museum/camera/dcc/data/2005-2006/2006_ps_a420.html?lang=us&categ=srs&page=psa&p=2) tells you which AC adapter is required for a particular camera.